# How to shuffle together a matrix and a response vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, shuffle

I have a dataset `X`, `y` where `X` is a matrix of observation `n*p` and `y` a response vector `n*1`.

I would like to shuffle `y` and the rows of `X` without losing the "line by line" relation.

How can I do that easily using `numpy` or `scipy` or `sklearn`?

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to keep the correspondence between rows in `X` and `y`? Generate random indices and index both arrays with them:

```
>>> perm = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
>>> X = X[perm]
>>> y = y[perm]
```